# Django Serialization KeyError (Django Rest Framework)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to write custome `create` method to make nested serialization, so i have this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    images = validated_data['commodity']['images']
    del validated_data['commodity']['images']
    commodity = Commodity.objects.create(**validated_data['commodity'])
    del validated_data['commodity']
    for image in images:
        CommodityImage.objects.create(commodity=commodity, **image)
    sizes = validated_data['outwear']['sizes']
    del validated_data['outwear']['sizes']
    clother = Clother.objects.create(commodity=commodity, **validated_data)
    outwear = Outwear.objects.create(clother=clother, **validated_data['outwear'])
    for size in sizes:
        outwear.sizes.add(size)
    return clother
```

Most of lines doing fine and outwear instance creates, but in can't add sizes to outwear instance, which has `sizes` as `ManyToMany` field in it's model and finally i get KeyError 'sizes' with no description.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

ADDED:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    images = validated_data['commodity']['images']
    del validated_data['commodity']['images']
    commodity = Commodity.objects.create(**validated_data['commodity'])
    del validated_data['commodity']
    for image in images:
        CommodityImage.objects.create(commodity=commodity, **image)

    sizes = validated_data['outwear']['sizes']
    # del validated_data['outwear']['sizes']

    clother = Clother.objects.create(commodity=commodity, **validated_data)
    outwear_type = validated_data['outwear']['outwear_type']
    name = validated_data['outwear']['name']
    outwear = Outwear.objects.create(clother=clother, outwear_type=outwear_type, name=name)
    for size in sizes:
        outwear.sizes.add(size)
    return clother
```

This solved the problem. Looks strange, because if i try to delete sizes again - i get the same 'sizes' problem. Also I have a:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.size)
```

as my size method (DecimalField).

Comment: The validated data depends on the model, serializer and the data you are posting to the view. Can you add those details too ?

Comment: @JPG I've just solved this problem, looks like bug, can you please comment this?

Comment: What you mean by *"can you please comment this"* ???

Comment: @JPG sorry, just added

Answer (score 0):

KeyError 'sizes' is  in this line

```
sizes = validated_data['outwear']['sizes']
```

check validated_data , maybe you need to see if sizes is  in outwear or not ?

Comment: That var 'sizes' get [<ClotherSize: 48.0>, <ClotherSize: 50.0>] from validated_data. So it looks like it works.

Comment: so adjust the logic in create fuction with  that data, good luck